# Vue.js and Laravel - how do we integrate the vuejs project with laravel 5*?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have created a project in Vue.js and now i just want to integrate that vuejs project with laravel 5 plus. Should it be done by the build or by the components of vue.? Thank You.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about here.   It's strange to have a front end developed with no knowledge about the backend, but even so, your question is too broad and unclear.  What specifically are you trying to integrate?

Comment: your vuejs project is a `vue-cli` project ? because laravel 5.* comes with vuejs preset out of the box. so basically you don't need to create a vuejs project separated from laravel

Comment: hey @Devon ,i am not  a frontend developer , i know laravel only, i got a project from someone its in vue.js only and he wanted me to i integrate that vuejs template in laravel (like how we integrate a html template with laravel) , i hope you will get this. and thanks for assist

Comment: Well, sounds like you need a frontend developer to program the vue.js code into your app, either coupled or through an api.  It's not going to be the same process as using an html template.

Comment: @ElAlamiAnas yes ,its vue-cli3 , but my project is quite big i cant re-write the whole code

Comment: it can be integrated using components that need more logic to interact with backend

Comment: @Devon oh ok, i saw a project on internet, they have used the build folder in the laravel and they were calling the main.js file from the welcome.blade.php is it a good way..?i dont think so its a good way because in future if we want to make any changes in the vue components  and we cant implement that in the vue folder, so i dont think so its the right way.

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim i am also thinking the samw but i am not able to find any proper refrence

Comment: you can put your components in `resources/assets/js` appropriately and build them using laravel mix, but before you need to add more logic and the needed components to your blade templates, we suppose you have a login form component built using vue.js in this case you could put it in login.blade.php template and add the logic that allows you to interact with the backend to get back user information ...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way for build Vue in Laravel

after you download your Laravel project, you open your terminal and type

> npm install

Vue auto installed in your Laravel project

> app/resources/assets/js/app.js

You need to change your Laravel route in web.php

```
Route::any('{all}', function(){
    return view('app');
})->where('all', '.*');
```

After you change your Laravel router, you can use Vue router for instead Laravel router.

Everything work for me.

Comment: ok , then after that? where should i place my vue components and other files or folders?? and which directory is that app/resources/assers/js/app.js..?a new folder will be create in our app folder?